Recursive definition and rank
The following is from Mac Lane's CWM, §7.2. Define a binary word as recursively as:

The length 0 binary word is $e_0$ (the empty word),
The length 1 binary word is $-$ (variable placeholder),
If $v$ and $w$ are binary words of length $m,n$ then the symbol $v \square w = (v) \square (w)$ is a binary word of length $m+n$.

Define the rank of a binary word recursively as:

$\rho(e_0) = 0$,
$\rho(-) = 0$,
$\rho(u \square v) = \rho(v) + \rho(w) + \text{length}(w) -1$

The book claims that $\rho(w) = 0$ implies that all the parentheses in $w$ start at the front. Why is this the case?

You could consider a small example first. But essentially, given $v$ of rank $0$, how can $\rho(v \square w)$ have still rank 0?

Please make your question self-contained. Nobody wants (or can) pick up a book to be able to make any sense of your question at all.

w is empty? But why?!

3 questions by the OP, all closed, for the same reason. Please check out How to ask a good question before you post your next one, otherwise that will be likely get closed again.
